# ClassNotFoundException when running Spark application with spark-submit

Tags: java, apache-spark, classnotfoundexception

I am not sure how to launch a Java app with `spark-submit`.

When I run the following command:

```
spark@mcava-master:/home/miren/NetBeansProjects$ /opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --class /home/miren/NetBeansProjects/SparkExample/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sparkexample/CountWords.java --master spark://192.168.1.105:7077 /home/miren/NetBeansProjects/SparkExample/target/SparkExample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar spark://192.168.1.105:7077
```

I get an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /home/miren/NetBeansProjects/SparkExample/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sparkexample/CountWords.java
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:689)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

How do I indicate the classpath?

Comment: @Miren: FYI, this question is [being discussed on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317469/812149).

Answer (score 11):

You need to call `spark-submit` in the following way:

```
spark-submit --class com.mycompany.sparkexample.CountWords 
             --master spark://192.168.1.105:7077 
             /home/miren/NetBeansProjects/SparkExample/target/SparkExample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
             {your-app-arguments-here}
```

The `--class` parameter takes the [fully qualified name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) of the object containing your main method.

The [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) contains more information about using `spark-submit` properly.

Comment: You should definitely have a look at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html. This explains how to use spark-submit properly :)

Comment: @Miren if this answered your question consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).